# How should I seed a random engine?

Tags: c++, c++11, random

I often see `std::random_device` used to seed random engines. In libstdc++, it defaults to using IA-32 RDRAND if a hardware RNG is available, otherwise `/dev/urandom`. libc++ has choices between `arc4random()`, `/dev/urandom` and `nacl_secure_random`. Windows might use `RtlGenRandom` or the Crypt API.

Of course there are many more options:

Intel-specific:

```
__asm__ __volatile__ ("rdtsc" : "=a"(lo));
```

PID:

```
getpid()
```

Thread ID:

```
std::this_thread::get_id()
```

Using chrono:

```
std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()
                        .time_since_epoch().count();
```

For libstdc++ this will not always be a nano-second resolution:

```
#ifdef _GLIBCXX_USE_CLOCK_REALTIME
      timespec tp;
      // -EINVAL, -EFAULT
#ifdef _GLIBCXX_USE_CLOCK_GETTIME_SYSCALL
      syscall(SYS_clock_gettime, CLOCK_REALTIME, &tp);
#else
      clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tp);
#endif
      return time_point(duration(chrono::seconds(tp.tv_sec)
                 + chrono::nanoseconds(tp.tv_nsec)));
#elif defined(_GLIBCXX_USE_GETTIMEOFDAY)
      timeval tv;
      // EINVAL, EFAULT
      gettimeofday(&tv, 0);
      return time_point(duration(chrono::seconds(tv.tv_sec)
                 + chrono::microseconds(tv.tv_usec)));
#else
      std::time_t __sec = std::time(0);
      return system_clock::from_time_t(__sec);
#endif
```

libc++ has a similar problem:

```
#ifdef CLOCK_REALTIME
    struct timespec tp;
    if (0 != clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tp))
        __throw_system_error(errno, "clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME) failed");
    return time_point(seconds(tp.tv_sec) + microseconds(tp.tv_nsec / 1000));
#else  // !CLOCK_REALTIME
    timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, 0); // :(
    return time_point(seconds(tv.tv_sec) + microseconds(tv.tv_usec));
#endif  // CLOCK_REALTIME
```

Other options include a hash of compile metadata(`__DATE__ __FILE__ __TIME__`, as one string), the heap, a hash of address of standard library functions, of a function, of the `this` pointer, etc. Or some combination of all of them?

Comment: What is wrong with `std::random_device`? Just be careful when using MinGW, I think it always returns 0 there or sth. Probably fixed by now.

Comment: could you tell more why do you need to seed RNG?

Comment: @Severin Pappadeux: Maybe, for some strange reason, he doesn't want to get the same sequence every time he runs the program? :)

Comment: @PaulGroke That is quite different from more usual case when he (or she) wants to split the run between multiple cores. Different problems have different solutions...

Comment: You should expand on your requirements. e.g., there's not much point in a 'secure' seed if you're not using a CSPRNG. There's no point using timestamps if you want reproducible results. There's no point using anything with nano-second variation unless you're instancing millions of random engines per second.

Comment: @Brett Hale: The reason for using nanosecond precision is not only to enable thousands/millions of instances per second but also to lower the predictability of the seed. Which can be more or less important, depending on the application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to succinctly, portably, and thoroughly seed the mt19937 PRNG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45069219/how-to-succinctly-portably-and-thoroughly-seed-the-mt19937-prng)

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to `std::random_device` I would suggest you use it. If not, I'd suggest concatenating everything you listed into one big string and then computing a hash-code over that string. (At least everything you listed that's not redundant, i.e. it wouldn't make much sense to use both `gettimeofday` *and* `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now`.)

Answer (score 0):

How you should seed your RNG depends on your purpose.

The options you mention are not high entropy seeds, and aren't appropriate for use in applications where the quality of the randomness is very important. For instance in numerical experiments for scientific, or financial, purposes. Or for cryptographic purposes.

The purpose of `std::random_device` is to provide a cross-platform source of seeds that *is* appropriate for those kinds of applications. If you are just making a game or something, unless it is a hard core strategy game and you *really* care, you are surely fine just using `srand(time(NULL))` and `rand` like people have been doing for at least 20 years.